# Lisp - How to call a function within another function?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I am trying to call the following function:

```
(defun c:Add ()
    (setq a (getint "Enter a number to add 2 to it"))
    (setq a (+ a 2))
)
```

Inside this LOOPER function:

```
(defun LOOPER (func)
    ;repeats 'func' until user enters 'no'
    (setq dummy "w")
    (while dummy
        (func) ;this is obviously the problem
        (setq order (getstring "\nContinue? (Y or N):"))
        (if (or (= order "N") (= order "n")) (setq dummy nil))
    )
)
```

Like this:

```
(defun c:Adder ()
    (LOOPER (c:Add))
)
```

How do I get around the fact that `func` is undefined in `LOOPER` function?

Comment: Wouldn't `(LOOPER (c:Add))` call `LOOPER` with the resulting **number** from calling `(c:Add)` once? It's not the same as passing the function `c:Add` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function as an argument to another function as demonstrated by the following example:

```
(defun c:add ( / a )
    (if (setq a (getint "\nEnter a number to add 2 to it: "))
        (+ a 2)
    )
)

(defun looper ( func )
    (while
        (progn
            (initget "Y N")
            (/= "N" (getkword "\nContinue? [Y/N] <Y>: "))
        )
        (func)
    )
)

(defun c:adder ( )
    (looper c:add)
)
```

Here, the symbol `c:add` is evaluated to yield the pointer to the function definition, which is then bound to the symbol `func` within the scope of the `looper` function. As such, within the scope of the `looper` function, the symbols `func` and `c:add` evaluate the same function.

Alternatively, you can pass the symbol `c:add` as a quoted symbol, in which case, the value of the symbol `func` is the symbol `c:add` which may then be evaluated to yield the function:

```
(defun c:add ( / a )
    (if (setq a (getint "\nEnter a number to add 2 to it: "))
        (+ a 2)
    )
)

(defun looper ( func )
    (while
        (progn
            (initget "Y N")
            (/= "N" (getkword "\nContinue? [Y/N] <Y>: "))
        )
        ((eval func))
    )
)

(defun c:adder ( )
    (looper 'c:add)
)
```

Passing a quoted symbol as a functional argument is more consistent with standard AutoLISP functions, such as `mapcar`, `apply` etc.

Comment: @lee mac great I will implement this technic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not send function name as the parameter, but here I give you a technic which can act like similar.

I don't have Autocad install on my machine so  I am unable to test this code. but you can remove if there is any small mistake or grab the concept so you can implement your own.

```
(defun c:Add ()
    (setq a (getint "Enter a number to add 2 to it"))
    (setq a (+ a 2))
)

(defun c:sub ()
    (setq a (getint "Enter a number to substract from 2:"))
    (setq a (-2 a))
)

(defun c:mul ()
    (setq a (getint "Enter a number to multiply with 2:"))
    (setq a (* a 2))
)


;----This function use to call other function from function name
;----Function name string is case sensitive
;----As per need you can Add function name to this function
(Defun callFunction(name)
(setq output nil)
;here you can add nested if condition but for simplicity I use If alone
(if (= name "C:Add")(setq output (C:Add)))
(if (= name "C:sub")(setq output (C:sub)))
(if (= name "C:mul")(setq output (C:mub)))
output
)

;----------Function end here



(defun LOOPER (func)
    ;repeats 'func' until user enters 'no'
    (setq dummy "w")
    (while dummy
        (callFunction func) ;Change here
        (setq order (getstring "\nContinue? (Y or N):"))
        (if (or (= order "N") (= order "n")) (setq dummy nil))
    )
)
```

You like run this program like this:

```
(defun c:Adder ()
    (LOOPER ("c:Add"))
)

(defun c:substaker ()
    (LOOPER ("c:sub"))
)

(defun c:multiplyer ()
    (LOOPER ("c:mul"))
)
```

Hope this helps:

Comment: You're a legend mate. Thanks!